# How to pack custom keyboard with an android app?

Tags: android, android-activity, keyboard

My app, a game, requires 10-14 alphanumeric keys instead of a full QWERTY keyboard. It will open up way more screen area for the user to interact. Pressing key everytime will go through a database of hundreds of thousands of words to find a match. And I don't want the keyboard to remain stuck during the search. Basically I want a custom keyboard with same basic principles of a default one- responsive, and app UI independent.

How can we achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "as it will be processor intensive" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly? "but will run as separate process from the main app" -- if your keyboard is "processor intensive", having it run in a separate process would make it *more* "processor intensive". Why are you trying to make things worse?

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. I should clarify- pressing key everytime will go through a database of hundreds of thousands of words to find a match. And I don't want the keyboard to remain stuck during the search. Basically I want a custom keyboard with same basic principles of a default one- responsive, app UI independent. I hope it clarifies my question.

Comment: "And I don't want the keyboard to remain stuck during the search" -- that has nothing to do with the keyboard and everything to do with the search itself, which needs to be done in a background thread.